# Safe way to include javascript file dynamically

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, session

I have a lang folder which contains the language variables for a website. Depending on the button clicked by the user, I want to include the desired file. So if the user chooses the english language, a session variable stores lang = 'en'. Then the file ./lang/en/client_vars.js in included so that I can call these variables. If the user chooses the chinese language, 'ch' is stored in the session and the file to include is ./lang/ch/client_vars.js.
Till now this is what I have thought:

1. `<script type="text/javascript" src="set_language.js"></script>` is included in the head section.
2. inside the set_language.js file, I get the session variable value like this:

   ```
   var language;
   $.ajaxSetup({cache: false})
   $.get('get_session.php', function (data) {
       language = data;
   });
   ```

   The get_session file was the file where the language session variable was declared and set.
3. Third step is to include the desired js file. This is where i am stuck. In a normal situation, if there was only one possible file, I would have done it in the head section as

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="./lang/en/client_vars.js"></script>
   ```

But since I need to get that variable with ajax first, I don't know how to deal with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$.get('get_session.php', function (data) {
    language = data;
    $.getScript('./lang/' + language + '/client_vars.js');
});
```

Comment: It would be even better if the initial `$.get()` could be made to return the actual script.

Comment: I will try that. However, I would appreciate some concern about the safety of the method used. In other threads I was reading how sometimes certain methods cause the code to be prone to bugs ...

Comment: @Pointy I do not know about that, I would like to hear your suggestion since any improvements are welcomed.